# Eway recurring - Any method to record invoice reference and description?

Tags: recurring-contributions, eway

Eway provides a way to add invoice ref and description by adding params like `InvoiceDescription` and `InvoiceReference` in [`alterPaymentProcessorParams` hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams/) provided by civicrm.

Unfortunately this does not work for recurring payments.

Eway does not seem to provide any flexibility to set `Invoice reference` or `Invoice Description` for a recurring payment. See the parameter that could be set - https://eway.io/api-v3/#recurring-payments.

Any thoughts for an alternative way to set these field values?

We are using Eway recurring extension to record payments in civi - https://civicrm.org/extensions/eway-recurring-payment-processor

Comment: Have you had a look at the 'other' eWAY Recurring extension? https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.ewayrecurring
I haven't tried it but the code at least seems to use `InvoiceDescription` and `InvoiceReference`.

Comment: The above extension also seems to be providing invoice description and reference for one-off payments only.

Comment: what about the Omnipay option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok - this has fixed for us and the reason was the incorrect param sent to the ProcessPayment operation. The correct way of sending the invoice params is -

```
$client = CRM_Core_Payment_EwayUtils::getClient($params['payment_processor_id']);
$endPoint = 'https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/managedpayment/ProcessPayment';

$paymentInfo = array(
  'man:managedCustomerID' => $params['managed_customer_id'],
  'man:amount' => $params['amount_in_cents'],
  'man:invoiceReference' => $params['invoice_id'],
  'man:invoiceDescription' => $params['description'],
);
$result = $client->call('man:ProcessPayment', $paymentInfo, '', $endPoint);
```

Note the correct usage of `man:invoiceReference` and `man:invoiceDescription`. It should be case-sensitive.